# neo4j: does not follow relationships until end

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to represent a network configuration with neo4j.
Here is the Cyper script I have been using so far :

```
 CREATE (router1:Router {name:'router1', defaultgw:'192.168.123.1'})
 CREATE (router2:Router {name:'router2', defaultgw:'172.31.39.1'})
 CREATE (gateway1:Gateway {name:'gateway1', ip:'192.168.123.1' })
 CREATE (network1:Network {name:'network1', cidr:'192.168.123.0/24'})
 CREATE (network2:Network {name:'network2', cidr:'10.23.47.0/24'})
 CREATE (network3:Network {name:'network3', cidr:'172.31.39.0/24'})
 CREATE (server10:Server {hostname:'server10', ip:'172.31.39.10'})
 CREATE (server1:Server {hostname:'server1', ip:'192.168.123.7'})
 CREATE (server2:Server {hostname:'server2', ip:'192.168.123.9'})
 CREATE (server3:Server {hostname:'server3', ip:'192.168.123.10', ip:'10.23.47.7'})
 CREATE (server4:Server {hostname:'server4', ip:'192.168.123.13'})
 CREATE (server5:Server {hostname:'server5', ip:'192.168.123.23'})
 CREATE (server6:Server {hostname:'server6', ip:'192.168.123.15', ip:'10.23.47.17'})
 CREATE
   (gateway1)-[:CONNECTED_TO {}]->(router1),
   (router2)-[:CONNECTED_TO {}]->(network3),
   (router1)-[:CONNECTED_TO {}]->(network1),
   (router1)-[:CONNECTED_TO {}]->(network2),
   (router1)-[:CONNECTED_TO {}]->(router2),
   (network1)-[:CONNECTED_TO {}]->(server1),
   (network1)-[:CONNECTED_TO {}]->(server2),
   (network1)-[:CONNECTED_TO {}]->(server3),
   (network2)-[:CONNECTED_TO {}]->(server3),
   (network1)-[:CONNECTED_TO {}]->(server4),
   (network1)-[:CONNECTED_TO {}]->(server5),
   (network1)-[:CONNECTED_TO {}]->(server6),
   (network2)-[:CONNECTED_TO {}]->(server6),
   (network3)-[:CONNECTED_TO {}]->(server10)
 WITH gateway1 AS g
   MATCH (g)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(r)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(n)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(s) RETURN g,r,n,s
 ;
```

However, the `MATCH` case does not let the rendering flow until the servers for the third network!

[image: Servers related to network3 are not getting represented]

What is wrong with my request and how can it be improved ?
Is there an other way to make this request, i.e. to represent **every** nodes having relationships or not with another instead of **only** those related to a single (here, `gateway1`) origin ?

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you asking for a query to get all 'Router', 'Gateway', 'Network', and 'Server' nodes? Or are you asking for a query to get all the nodes in the subtree rooted at `gateway1` (including `server10`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are asking for a query to get all the nodes in the subtree rooted at `gateway1`, then your `MATCH` does not work because it only matches paths with exactly 3 `CONNECTED_TO` relationships. The path to `server10` requires 4 hops.

To return full paths with 1 or more `CONNECTED_TO` relationships rooted at `gateway1`, this should work (the `WHERE` clause filters out paths where `x` is a non-leaf node):

```
...
WITH gateway1 AS g
MATCH p=(g)-[:CONNECTED_TO*]->(x)
WHERE NOT (x)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->()
RETURN p;
```

And, if you also want to be able to return just the root gateway node when it has no other nodes in its subgraph, you can change `*` to `*0..`:

```
...
WITH gateway1 AS g
MATCH p=(g)-[:CONNECTED_TO*0..]->(x)
WHERE NOT (x)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->()
RETURN p;
```

Answer (score 1):

As @cybersam says the servers in network 3 are four hops away because they need to traverse to routers.

An alternative to his solution if you know you are looking for `:Server` nodes 3 to 4 hops out you could use a query like the following.

```
...
WITH gateway1 AS g
MATCH p=(g)-[:CONNECTED_TO*3..4]->(:Server)
RETURN p
```